# I don't know what is wrong in my algorithm in code for Google Code Jam 2018 1B-B

Tags: python, algorithm

Now the contest is over, so I want to ask my algorithmic fails on my code.

[This is the problem. If anyone interested, you can see it at here](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/0000000000007764/dashboard/000000000003675b)

```
def solve():
    S = int(input())
    D, A, B, M, N = [], [], [], [], []

    for i in range(S):
        d, a, b = [int(c) for c in input().split(" ")]
        D.append(d); A.append(a); B.append(b)
        M.append(d+a); N.append(d-b)

    straightMstart, straightNstart = [0]*(S), [0]*(S)
    crossedMstart, crossedNstart = [0]*(S), [0]*(S) # cross over
    for i in range(1, S):
        if M[i] == M[i-1]:
            straightMstart[i] = straightMstart[i-1]
            crossedNstart[i] = crossedNstart[i-1]
        else:
            straightMstart[i] = i

        if N[i] == N[i-1]:
            straightNstart[i] = straightNstart[i-1]
            crossedMstart[i] = crossedMstart[i-1]
        else:
            straightNstart[i] = i

        if M[i] != M[i-1]:
            crossedNstart[i] = straightNstart[i-1]
        if N[i] != N[i-1]:
            crossedMstart[i] = straightMstart[i-1]

    maxlen = 1
    maxlensubsets = 1
    for i in range(1, S):
        thislen = i - min(crossedMstart[i], crossedNstart[i]) + 1
        if maxlen < thislen:
            maxlen = thislen
            maxlensubsets = 1
        elif maxlen == thislen:
            maxlensubsets += 1

    # print(crossedNstart)
    # print(crossedMstart)
    return "%d %d" % (maxlen, maxlensubsets)

testcase = int(input())
for tc in range(1, testcase+1):
    print("Case %d: %s" % (tc, solve()))
```

I used crossed max length to find the maximum size of set.(for M and Ns)

I will give you the following example to make easier to understand my logic:

```
# Let's suppose that the M and N is:
M (=D[i]+A[i]) = [  9,  9, 18, 22, 22]
N (=D[i]-B[i]) = [-10, -5,  7, -1, -1]

# Straight Start means starting index for same value.
# M=9 starts from index 0, M=18 starts from index 2, M=22 starts from index 3
straightMstart = [0, 0, 2, 3, 3]
# Same logic applied to straightNstart
straightNstart = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]

# Crossed Start means cross-starting index of opponent array.    
# For crossedMstart, you start from N[i] and climb N then cross to climb M
# The reason why I swapped order of cNs and cMs is that both arrays are based on opponent arrays
crossedNstart = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
crossedMstart = [0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```

I'm really confusing, I don't really understand what is the point of my fault. Please help me to correct my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my algorithm does not handling multiple crossover.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has multiple ways it could fail. The simplest of them is entering a `string` in any of the inputs. Then I do see a problem with `straightNstart[i]` which is always zero for the current iteration if `N[i]` or `M[i]` match `N[i-1]` or `M[i-1]`. This sets the `crossedMstart[i]` and `crossedNstart[i]` values to `0`. Another problem is when `S <= 1` which ignores both loops.

The first problem is easy to solve which potentially covers the problems for d, a, b, testcase where d, a, b, testcase should raise only a TypeError:

```
S = input("[description]")
if S.isdigit():
    S = int(S)
    if S <= 1:
        raise ValueError("Value must be greater then 1")
else:
    raise TypeError("Value must be numeric")
```

For the other problem it could be possible to iterate twice so that the `straightNstart[i]`, `straightMstart[i]` assignments have any effect on the outcome ( at least not when M[i] or N[i] are not equal to M[i-1] or N[i-1] ).

Comment: You can guarantee that `S` is integer.

Comment: If `S=1` then no matter what value will come because the answer will always 1.